# Batch File To Change Share Permissions of Windows 10 Folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 from 7 on all of my computers, I have 4. I use Cobian backup which used to work fine on windows 7 however on 10 the shares of the folders aren't set correctly and although they say they are shared they don't appear across the network so I cant back them up.

I have however found I can go into each folder and change the permissions manually and they do appear but the problem is I have around 500 folders so I wanted to know if there was a quick command or batch file that could be run to set sharing permissions to everyone for every folder in the parent folder so I don't have to do it individually?

Answer (score 1):

Try toggling the inheritance on the main parent folder.  The permissions should trickle down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `icacls` to change the permissions, like

```
icacls "C:\myFolder" /grant Everyone:M
```

For changing permissions to all sub directories you can use a `for` loop and give folder name to the icacls command,

```
@echo off
set Dir=C:\FolderName

for /d  /r "%Dir%" %%a in (*) do (
    echo Setting permissions for %%~dpa Folder
    icacls %%~dpa /grant Everyone:M
)
```

Adjust set Dir = C:\FolderName with your path (base Folder).